# How is it possible, that ajaxing is much more slower in Chrome and IE than Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to ask you to find the point, why the site -I'm working on- is slow.

the conditions of the problem:

- large row count (so I think maybe the problem is related to this.)
- there is ajaxing event (I have tired to comment it out and the problem disappeared)
- using not Mozilla (this freeze effect appear in IE and Chrome)

description of the problem (see the image):

- I change the value of input
- after there is an ajax call (in order to calculate prize) and **it takes in FF about 30 ms otherwise more than 1 s**
- there is a freeze until the ajax finished (but ajax is not set to async:false)
- only after that can I change the next input

I have tired to reproduce the error, but I could't. So see the original site:

<del>site: foto/fotokidolgozas/elohivas-beallitasok.php</del>

<del>Log in and pass: d838292@rtrtr.com</del>

**Update**: It works now fine, the trick is the following:

I use hidden input fields, their values are json_encode-d strings. I can process them anytime with js.

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Code:

```
$('#cikkek,#magic_bar').on("change","select,textarea,input[type!=hidden]",function(event_object){
    if( $(this).attr('name') == "kijelolve" && !$(this).parents('#magic_bar').length)return true;

    var cikk_id = $(this).parents('.cikk').attr('id');
    var cikk_tipus = $("input[name=cikk_tipus]").val();
    var tulajdonsag = $(this).attr('name');     
    var ertek = $(this).val();
    if(ertek == "-1")return false;      
    if($(this).is('[type=checkbox]'))ertek = $(this).prop("checked")?'1':'0';

    if(cikk_tipus=='fotokidolgozas' && (tulajdonsag=='meret'||tulajdonsag=='vagas'))
        {
            var sor = $(event_object.target).parents('.cikk');
            var act_meret = sor.find('select[name=meret]').val();
            var act_fill = sor.find('select[name=vagas]').val();
            var act_zold_class = sor.find("input[name=zold_"+act_meret+"]").val()=="1" ?"zold":"feher" ;
            var name = "src_"+act_meret+"_"+act_fill;                   
            var name2 = "szoveges_uzenet_"+act_meret+"_"+act_fill;                  
            sor.find(".img_cont").find("img").attr("src",sor.find("input[name="+name+"]").val());   
            sor.find(".szoveges_uzenet").text(sor.find("input[name="+name2+"]").val());
            sor.find(".dpi_megfelel").text(sor.find("input[name=minoseg_"+act_meret+"]").val()+" ("+sor.find("input[name=dpi_"+act_meret+"]").val()+" dpi)");
            sor.find("select[name=meret]").removeClass("feher zold").addClass(act_zold_class);
        }

    var before = now();

    //this is the ajax part
    if(ajax_modositaskor)
    $.post('/_fn/cikk/mod.php',{
        'cikk_tipus':cikk_tipus,
        'cikk_id':cikk_id,
        'tulajdonsag':tulajdonsag,
        'ertek':ertek
        },function(a){
            var elapsed = now() - before;
            if(a[0]!="1")
            {
                //error
                alert(a[0]);
                return;
            }
            if(a[1]!="-1")
            {
                //there is new price
                $(event_object.target).parents('.cikk').find('.ar').text(a[1]);     
            }
            if(a[2]!="-1")$('#cikkek_ara').text(a[2]);
            osszegzest_frissit(a[3]);               
            var php_time = Math.round(a[4])
            a_min = Math.min(a_min,elapsed);
            p_min = Math.min(p_min,parseFloat(php_time));
            a_max = Math.max(a_max,elapsed);
            p_max = Math.max(p_max,parseFloat(php_time));
            if(!a_avg)a_avg = elapsed;else a_avg= Math.round((a_avg+elapsed)/2);
            if(!p_avg)p_avg = php_time;else p_avg = Math.round((p_avg+php_time)/2);             
            trace("ajax="+elapsed+"\tphp="+php_time+"\tajax_min="+a_min+"\tphp_min="+p_min+"\tajax_max="+a_max+" \tphp_max="+p_max+"\tajax_avg="+a_avg+" \tphp_avg="+p_avg);                

        },"json").error(function() { postHiba() });


});
```

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I dont have difference between FF14b,IE9,Chrome19 on my system. Execution time of request (from Network tabs in DevTools) and visually - all equals.

Comment: I have the same issue with one of my scripts, using Comet with Ajax: one Chrome agent is freezing, and another one (out of the box) is not.

Comment: @AndrewD. I suppose you have faseter coumputer, and that this process requires a lot of memory/cpu resource - don't it?

Comment: If you do most of your developing in firefox, you have probably cached most of your calls, including the dns lookups and, which could take a second.

Comment: @kennebec If I have only a few rows (not about 100) than this additional 1 s does not occur neither in Chrome nor in IE

Comment: I don't know if it is important factor, but every lines contains a lot of ´<input TYPE=HIDDEN>´ tags that stores additional information. I think it may have influence on speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the hidden data was too large ([see my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11047383/669677)), and it decreased the processing time. (Firefox seems to be well coded, because this does not mattered)

Now the problem is fixed.